# wildfly 9.0 standalone cluster with httpd2.4. and mod_cluster1.3.1

Tags: jboss, wildfly, httpd.conf, mod-cluster

I want to set up a standalone Wildfly cluster with 2 nodes. For this purpose I set up 2 fedora22 virtual machines. On both nodes I installed Wildfly 9.0.0.Final and run it with `standalone-ha.xml` configuration file. On first node I also installed  httpd 2.4 and mod_cluster 1.3.1. Current setting are listed below. 
On both machines I disabled firewall and SELinux.

**Node1 configuration** (192.168.2.240)

*mod_cluster.conf*

```
LoadModule cluster_slotmem_module       modules/mod_cluster_slotmem.so
LoadModule proxy_cluster_module modules/mod_proxy_cluster.so
LoadModule advertise_module     modules/mod_advertise.so
LoadModule manager_module       modules/mod_manager.so
CreateBalancers 1
<IfModule manager_module>
 Listen 192.168.2.240:6666
 ManagerBalancerName mycluster
 <VirtualHost 192.168.2.240:6666>
   KeepAliveTimeout 300
   MaxKeepAliveRequests 0
   AdvertiseFrequency 5
   ServerAdvertise On
   EnableMCPMReceive
   <Location />
     Require all granted
   </Location>
   <Location /mod_cluster_manager>
     SetHandler mod_cluster-manager
     Require all granted
   </Location>
 </VirtualHost>
```

*httpd.conf*

ServerRoot "/etc/httpd"

Listen 80
   Include conf.modules.d/*.conf
   User apache
   Group apache
   ServerAdmin root@localhost

```
<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all denied
</Directory>

DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"
<Directory "/var/www">
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory "/var/www/html">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.html
</IfModule>

<Files ".ht*">
    Require all denied
</Files>

ErrorLog "logs/error_log"
LogLevel debug

<IfModule log_config_module>
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common
    <IfModule logio_module>
      LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %I %O" combinedio
    </IfModule>
    CustomLog "logs/access_log" combined
</IfModule>

<IfModule alias_module>
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/var/www/cgi-bin/" 
</IfModule>

<Directory "/var/www/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<IfModule mime_module>    
    TypesConfig /etc/mime.types
    AddType application/x-compress .Z
    AddType application/x-gzip .gz .tgz
    AddType text/html .shtml
    AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .shtml
</IfModule>

AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

<IfModule mime_magic_module>
    MIMEMagicFile conf/magic
</IfModule>

EnableSendfile on

#Includes mod_cluster.conf
IncludeOptional conf.d/*.conf

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ProxyPass / balancer://mycluster stickysession=JSESSIONID|jsessionid nofailover=On
    ProxyPassReverse / balancer://mycluster
    <Location />
        Require all granted
    </location>
</VirtualHost>
```

*standalone-ha.xml* (I am pasting only important parts)

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<server name="node1" xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:3.0">

        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:modcluster:2.0">
            <mod-cluster-config advertise-socket="modcluster" connector="ajp">
                <dynamic-load-provider>
                    <load-metric type="cpu"/>
                </dynamic-load-provider>
            </mod-cluster-config>
        </subsystem>

        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:undertow:2.0">
            <buffer-cache name="default"/>
            <server name="default-server">
                <ajp-listener name="ajp" socket-binding="ajp"/>
                <http-listener name="default" socket-binding="http" redirect-socket="https"/>
                <host name="cloudflow" alias="localhost">
                    <location name="/" handler="welcome-content"/>
                    <filter-ref name="server-header"/>
                    <filter-ref name="x-powered-by-header"/>
                </host>
            </server>
            <servlet-container name="default">
                <jsp-config/>
                <websockets/>
            </servlet-container>
            <handlers>
                <file name="welcome-content" path="${jboss.home.dir}/welcome-content"/>
            </handlers>
            <filters>
                <response-header name="server-header" header-name="Server" header-value="WildFly/9"/>
                <response-header name="x-powered-by-header" header-name="X-Powered-By" header-value="Undertow/1"/>
            </filters>
        </subsystem>

    <interfaces>
        <interface name="management">
            <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address.management:192.168.2.240}"/>
        </interface>
        <interface name="public">
            <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address:192.168.2.240}"/>
        </interface>
        <interface name="unsecure">
            <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address.unsecure:127.0.0.1}"/>
        </interface>
    </interfaces>

<socket-binding-group name="standard-sockets" default-interface="public" port-offset="${jboss.socket.binding.port-offset:0}">
    <socket-binding name="management-http" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.http.port:9990}"/>
    <socket-binding name="management-https" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.https.port:9993}"/>
    <socket-binding name="ajp" port="${jboss.ajp.port:8009}"/>
    <socket-binding name="http" port="${jboss.http.port:8080}"/>
    <socket-binding name="https" port="${jboss.https.port:8443}"/>
    <socket-binding name="jgroups-mping" port="0" multicast-address="${jboss.default.multicast.address:230.0.0.4}" multicast-port="45700"/>
    <socket-binding name="jgroups-tcp" port="7600"/>
    <socket-binding name="jgroups-tcp-fd" port="57600"/>
    <socket-binding name="jgroups-udp" port="55200" multicast-address="${jboss.default.multicast.address:230.0.0.4}" multicast-port="45688"/>
    <socket-binding name="jgroups-udp-fd" port="54200"/>
    <socket-binding name="modcluster" port="0" multicast-address="224.0.1.105" multicast-port="23364"/>
    <socket-binding name="txn-recovery-environment" port="4712"/>
    <socket-binding name="txn-status-manager" port="4713"/>
    <outbound-socket-binding name="mail-smtp">
        <remote-destination host="localhost" port="25"/>
    </outbound-socket-binding>
</socket-binding-group>
```

**Node2 configuration** (192.168.2.226)

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>

<server name="node2" xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:3.0">
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:modcluster:2.0">
        <mod-cluster-config advertise-socket="modcluster" connector="ajp">
            <dynamic-load-provider>
                <load-metric type="cpu"/>
            </dynamic-load-provider>
       </mod-cluster-config>
    </subsystem>

   <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:undertow:2.0">
        <buffer-cache name="default"/>
        <server name="default-server">
            <ajp-listener name="ajp" socket-binding="ajp"/>
            <http-listener name="default" socket-binding="http" redirect-socket="https"/>
            <host name="cloudflow" alias="localhost">
                <location name="/" handler="welcome-content"/>
                <filter-ref name="server-header"/>
                <filter-ref name="x-powered-by-header"/>
            </host>
        </server>
        <servlet-container name="default">
            <jsp-config/>
            <websockets/>
        </servlet-container>
        <handlers>
            <file name="welcome-content" path="${jboss.home.dir}/welcome-content"/>
        </handlers>
        <filters>
            <response-header name="server-header" header-name="Server" header-value="WildFly/9"/>
            <response-header name="x-powered-by-header" header-name="X-Powered-By" header-value="Undertow/1"/>
        </filters>
    </subsystem>


<interfaces>
    <interface name="management">
        <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address.management:192.168.2.226}"/>
    </interface>
    <interface name="public">
        <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address:192.168.2.226}"/>
    </interface>
    <interface name="unsecure">
        <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address.unsecure:127.0.0.1}"/>
    </interface>
</interfaces>

<socket-binding-group name="standard-sockets" default-interface="public" port-offset="${jboss.socket.binding.port-offset:0}">
    <socket-binding name="management-http" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.http.port:9990}"/>
    <socket-binding name="management-https" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.https.port:9993}"/>
    <socket-binding name="ajp" port="${jboss.ajp.port:8009}"/>
    <socket-binding name="http" port="${jboss.http.port:8080}"/>
    <socket-binding name="https" port="${jboss.https.port:8443}"/>
    <socket-binding name="jgroups-mping" port="0" multicast-address="${jboss.default.multicast.address:230.0.0.4}" multicast-port="45700"/>
    <socket-binding name="jgroups-tcp" port="7600"/>
    <socket-binding name="jgroups-tcp-fd" port="57600"/>
    <socket-binding name="jgroups-udp" port="55200" multicast-address="${jboss.default.multicast.address:230.0.0.4}" multicast-port="45688"/>
    <socket-binding name="jgroups-udp-fd" port="54200"/>
    <socket-binding name="modcluster" port="0" multicast-address="224.0.1.105" multicast-port="23364"/>
    <socket-binding name="txn-recovery-environment" port="4712"/>
    <socket-binding name="txn-status-manager" port="4713"/>
    <outbound-socket-binding name="mail-smtp">
        <remote-destination host="localhost" port="25"/>
    </outbound-socket-binding>
</socket-binding-group>
```

**my application settings**

*pom.xml*

```
<contextRoot>/</contextRoot>
```

*jboss-web.xml*

```
<jboss-web>  
    <context-root>/</context-root>
    <virtual-host>cloudflow</virtual-host>
</jboss-web>
```

*jboss-web.xml*

```
 <distributable />
```

I start httpd with `systemctl start httpd` and then i run Wildfly with `./standalone.sh -c standalone-ha.xml`.
Servers starts without an error and deploy application. I can see my application on both nodes on localhost:8080

On 192.168.2.240:6666/mod_cluster_manager i can see following screen:

[image: screenshot]

When i want to get my app in browser on address http://192.168.2.240/ but i get 503 Service Unavailable when i restart httpd and page 404 - Not found few seconds letter.
On http://192.168.2.240:6666/ i get fedora test page. [Error log](http://pastebin.ca/3207966) of httpd dont show any error only debug messages.

I think i have problem in configuration where my app gets deployed.

Comment: Does it change anything if you deploy your app so as it has context ```/cloudflow``` (without vhost config) instead of ```/``` ?  It might be a bug in mc. Gonna try to reproduce.

Comment: no nothing helped so i changed httpd to 2.2. and mod_cluster to 1.2.6 and it works fine. I think there is bug in newest modcluster or httpd.
Httpd tries to ping port 27233 which is not even open

Comment: Thanks Domen for digging into it. I'll dissect the latest mod_cluster and get back to you.

Comment: I managed to make it work today. Problem was on command:
ServerAdvertise On 
I changed it to:
ServerAdvertise On IP:port
after that it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was on command: ServerAdvertise On I changed it to: ServerAdvertise On IP:6666

I also delelted whole virtual Host section for port 80 in httpd.conf
After that it worked